# Auto-Focus based on tapped area for embedded camera on Safari IOS and Chrome Android browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, webrtc

I'm trying to have the same behavior of most mobile camera apps, that auto adjusts the focus based on the image tapped area.
So thats my main goal and below it is listed my tries...

I've played so far with **focusMode**, **focusDistance** and **pointsOfInterest**.
It seems that the **focusDistance** is not implemented yet and, different of the **pointsOfInterest**, it is not listed when I call:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints();
```

About the **pointsOfInterest**, I tried to set it with different values as a constraint but it do not seem to make any difference:

```
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
        video: {
            width: 320,
            height: 320,
            facingMode: { exact: 'environment' },
            pointsOfInterest: {x: 0.5, y: 0.5}
        }, 
        audio: false
    })
```

I've also tried to change it on the fly(after getting the user media):

```
mediaStreamTrack.applyConstraints({advanced : [{pointsOfInterest: { x:0.5, y:0.5 }}]});
```

About the **focusDistance** I didn't play much since it is not even shown in the capabilities list.

And about the focusMode, it do not seems to help. I was able to change among 3 modes:

```
["manual", "single-shot", "continuous"]
```

And I still wonder what is the "manual" mode for, since the **focusDistance** capability is not available.
And I've tried "manual" mode along with **pointsOfInterest** with no luck.

- *I would like to emphasize that it is not about mobile application or webview, its a web page with an embedded camera. ;)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this since then?

Comment: Hi @Huy, I haven't researched about it anymore, sorry!